# Using REGEX to process file contents instead of a line by line basis

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use `C#` to split a SQL script which contains regions by using `Regex.Split()` which I can't seem to get the pattern for - I really struggle with the concept of Regex and find it completely bewildering in most circumstances, although I do understand it to be the best solution to achieve the following.

Input string (which is 100'000* the below hence the sluggishness of my method)

```
--#region someregioncomment
aaaa
bbbb
--#endregion
```

Where each return is `\r\n`.

Output `Dictionary<string, string>`

- Key: `--#region someregioncomment`
- Value: `aaaa\r\nbbbb`

At the moment I am doing this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> regionValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(SSBS))
{
  string strCurrentRegion = "";
  string strCurrentRegionContents = "";
  while (sr.Peek() != -1)
  {
    string strCurrentLine = sr.ReadLine();
    if (strCurrentLine.Contains("--#region"))
    {
      strCurrentRegion = strCurrentLine;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCurrentRegion))
    {
      continue;
    }
    else if (strCurrentLine.Contains("--#endregion"))
    {
      regionValues.Add(strCurrentRegion, strCurrentRegionContents);
      strCurrentRegion = "";
    }
    else
    {
      strCurrentRegionContents += ("\r\n" + strCurrentLine);
    }
  }
}
```

However I felt that this could be achieved with a `Regex` pattern combined with `Regex.Split()` - I can't seem to get the jist of what the pattern should look like...

I have atttempted:

```
(--#region.*?)\n
(--#region)\w*
```

I just can't seem to get it! Any help for my desired output appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: So - basically you want to pull all of the content in-between #region blocks, into a dictionary - with the dictionary Key being the name of the region?

Comment: @DaveBish Correct! My method seems very sluggish (a line by line basis)

Comment: For large files a line by line is just fine however you can improve a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `String.Split` and the `Regex` is it loads the whole file into memory.
So, why don't you read the script line by line with a `StreamReader`?

```
Dictionary<string, string> regions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string regionName = null;
StringBuilder regionString = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText("MyFile.txt"))
{
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

        if (line.StartsWith("--#region "))         // Beginning of the region
        {
            regionName = line.Substring(10);
        }
        else if (line.StartsWith("--#endregion"))  // End of the region
        {
            if (regionName == null)
                throw new InvalidDataException("#endregion found without a #region.");
            regions.Add(regionName, regionString.ToString());
            regionString.Clear();
        }
        else if (regionName != null) // If the line is in a region
        {
            regionString.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Be careful with the Dictionary. If your file contains multiple regions with the same name. It will crash.

Few advices:

- Use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating the string (for better performance).
- Use `String.StartsWith` instead of `String.Contains` for 2 reasons: performance (`StartWith` is easier to check, and imagine you have a string containing `"--#region"` in your SQL what happen ?!).
- To create a new line, don't use `"\r\n"` which is environment specific, but `Environment.NewLine` instead.
- `sr.Peek()` shouldn't be used to test the end of the file/stream. There is a property designed for this: `StreamReader.EndOfStream`.

Comment: Due to the length of the file - I don't think a line by line basis is going to be the quickest way (be that a `StringReader` or `StreamReader`)

Comment: This would probably be faster than a regex on a very large string, and use far less memory as well.

Comment: Takes about 400ms here, for 100,000 regions with 10 lines of text each.